drf allauth google signup sign in
Im using django allauth for google signup sign in after successfully sign in, all the functions which need authentication will be performed after user is authenticated
but i dont know how to authenticate the user in backend after sign in sign up
using customuser inheriting abstractbaseuser and a user with additional required field
tried google sign in but want to authenticate the user
